# ValidationError: Profile validation failed: _id: Path `_id` is required

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

ValidationError: Profile validation failed: _id: Path `_id` is required.

> I am Trying to Create Custom Unique Id in Mongodb.. getting a 
>   validation error path required for _id.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  _id: {type: String, required: true},
  seq: { type: Number, default: 180000 },
  contact: String,
  altemail: String,
  presentaddress1: String,
  presentaddress2: String,
  zipecode: Number,
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

});
var Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);

var entitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  testvalue: {type: String}
});

entitySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var doc = this;
  Profile.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'entityId'}, {$inc: { seq: 1} }, function(error, Profile)   {
      if(error)
          return next(error);
      doc.testvalue = Profile.seq;
      next();
  });


});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Comment: `{ _id: false }` in the schema options if you want to override the defaults.

Comment: I did the changes now facing another issue. MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving

Comment: The answer does not say "remove the `_id` from the schema". It says "add to schema options" `new Schema({ ... },{ _id: false })`. But you **must** supply the `_id` value on every document created. Look for other posts on the subject and learn why this is generally not a good idea.